How do I set watchpoint in Flutter?
Does Flutter have watchpoint functionality? When I was doing iOS development, I used lldb for debugging, and I could trigger a breakpoint when the 'person.age' variable changed using the following command:
watchpoint set variable person.age

not really, instead of watchpoints you can only use conditional breakpoints or logging breakpoints

That's a shame, because conditional breakpoints and logging breakpoints are completely different from watchpoint functionality. The former can only set breakpoints for executable statements, but I don't know where the person.age variable will be modified, so I can't set a breakpoint unless I implement a set method. However, in that case, I could just use a regular breakpoint to break in the set method.
